# Communicating Swift iOS and Java

Tags: java, sql, swift, cross-platform

How can my Swift and Java programs communicate a value? e.g. Swift puts "hello" to web, java retrieves and prints "hello"

Comment: Your question is probably too broad.  If you have a specific question about database, Java, or iOS code then ask it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to create web service for java program. So you can directly
   call java function from any platform. You can use

   > jersey framework

   for creating web service.
2. This will communicate by JSON Response and JSON Request.

Comment: Can you please explain what that is, I am new to cross-platform communication. Also what about the swift side of things. Can you give me a phrase that I can research?

Comment: Webservice is thing which can use be used for cross plate form communication.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm  for java problem

Comment: call from iOS like json request.

Comment: This answer is perfect for any cross platform communication

Comment: You can also get response from android also.

Comment: So what would I put in my code and do I need a web server?

Comment: 100% you need web server..otherwise you can run on localhost Too

Comment: How would I put this in my code? In a function? What would I put in that function?

Comment: You need to have full knowledge about of oops in java and servlet + JSON + iOS JSON parsing

Comment: I don't but I really want to learn. What phrases can I research?

Comment: 1. Custom function

Comment: 2. Webservice using java by jersey

Comment: "Custom function" What?

Comment: 3. call json service and parse response swift

Comment: I don't understand jersey, is there an example of this thing I can look at? Surely its simpler to have a web variable which both programs can edit and read?

Comment: tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm this is best article for jersey....hit+1

Comment: And what about swift 3?

Comment: search for alamofire...for swift 3 hit+1